# DbSet.Remove() seems like to remove sometimes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing

Hello I have this project on Entity Framework for an exam, I have 157 test to pass and I pass 155, the last 2 are very similar to others but I dont understand why fails, I put some code so I can explain better:

```
 public void GetUsers_OnDeletedObject_Throws() {
            Site.Delete();
            Assert.That(() => Site.GetUsers(), Throws.TypeOf<InvalidOperationException>()); }
```

I defined the Delete() method to recorsively call Delete to resources in the site(like users), then remove the site from the context.
From now on any method in the site must throw InvalidOperationException because the site doesn't exist anymore, but in some way Site.GetUsers() find a site and dont throw.
The real mistery is if I try to insert other methods (written in same way) between the delete and the assert the extra method throw InvalidOperationException!

Site.Delete() code:

```
    using (var ctx = new SiteContext(connectionString))
    {
        var site = ctx.Sites.Find(Name);
        foreach (var a in GetAuctions()) ctx.Auctions.Remove(a);
        foreach (var s in GetSessions()) ctx.Sessions.Remove(s);
        foreach (var u in GetUsers()) ctx.Users.Remove(u);
        ctx.Sites.Remove(site);
        ctx.SaveChanges();   
    }
```

Part of GetUsers where should throw

```
public IEnumerable<IUser>GetUsers()
{
    using (var ctx = new SiteContext(connectionString))
    {
        var site = ctx.Sites.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == Name);
        AlreadyDeleted(site);
```

AlreadyDeleted() code:

```
public static void AlreadyDeleted(object o)
{
    if (null == o) throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show us what `Delete()` and `GetUsers()` does before we have a chance to guess. But... if this is an exam, are you sure you should ask here?

Comment: I think i can ask here,It's a long time project I can read documentation on the web and I already did the code, I just asking for help on why sometime isn't working like it should, anyway i showed the code u asked so It can be more helpful

Comment: What code you expect to throw an exception? `SingleOrDefault` will not throw, but return `null` when site is not found. Can you show `AlreadyDeleted` then?

Comment: Is `Name` the primary key on `Site`?

Comment: I don't see how `Site.Delete();` calls what you show under `Site.Delete();`. If `Delete` is an instance method of  `Site` then it will never remove the `Site` object from your code. Seems like you're mixing up persistence patterns. In EF's repository pattern, entities don't delete themselves.

Comment: AlreadyDeleted is a simple if (obj is null) throw InvalidOperationException(), the Delete() of Users call ctx.Users.Remove(user) in the users class and logout make the session invalid(change the datetime), I'll add more code to explain in the main question

Comment: Have you tried to debug your test? I would also check if a site is in the database after call to `SaveChanges` when you debug.